# Yahoo gemini reporting API error

Tags: php, yahoo, yahoo-api

I'm trying to use Reporting API https://developer.yahoo.com/gemini/guide/reporting/cubes/#performance-stats

But when I try to request URI to create report - I receive response 400 with message

```
{"errors":[{"errIndex":-1,"code":"E40000_INVALID_INPUT","message":"Entity (publisher or advertiser id) not available","description":""}],"response":null,"timestamp":"2016-11-22 15:25:24"}
```

Data being passed to api endpoint:

```
$data = [
    'cube' => 'performance_stats',
    'fields' => [
        ['field'=> 'Ad ID'],
        ['field'=> 'Advertiser ID'],
        ['field'=> 'Day'],
        ['field'=> 'Spend'],
    ],
    'filters' => [
        ['field' => 'Advertiser ID', 'operator' => '=', 'value' => xxxxx],
        ['field' => 'Campaign ID', 'operator' => 'IN', 'values' => [xxxxx]],
        ['field' => 'Day', 'operator' => 'between', 'from' => '2016-11-20', 'to' => '2016-11-21'],
    ]
];
```

It seems to be OK, mostly copied from docs.

Advertiser used in filter exists. I can request it via URL `https://api.gemini.yahoo.com/v2/rest/advertiser/xxxxx`, campaign - as well.

I've found few forum discussions, but they don't really help:

1.https://forums.developer.yahoo.net/discussion/7009/gemini-reporting-help

2.https://forums.developer.yahoo.net/discussion/7091/gemini-reports-api-no-longer-working-as-expected

3.https://forums.developer.yahoo.net/discussion/7347/yahoo-gemini-custom-reporting

Did anybody face such issue?

Comment: Also having this issue, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: use json_encode($data)

Comment: in js case use JSON.stringify(data)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Solution:-

```
    $access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";
    $headers = array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token, 'Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json');
    $postdata = [
    'cube' => 'performance_stats',
    'fields' => [
        ['field'=> 'Ad ID'],
        ['field'=> 'Advertiser ID'],
        ['field'=> 'Day'],
        ['field'=> 'Spend'],
    ],
    'filters' => [
        ['field' => 'Advertiser ID', 'operator' => '=', 'value' => xxxxx],
        ['field' => 'Campaign ID', 'operator' => 'IN', 'values' => [xxxxx]],
        ['field' => 'Day', 'operator' => 'between', 'from' => '2016-11-20', 'to' => '2016-11-21'],
    ]
];
    $curl = curl_init("https://api.gemini.yahoo.com/v2/rest/reports/custom/");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postdata));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Read the doc here https://developer.yahoo.com/gemini/guide/reporting/

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc, the answer is: “Advertiser ID” and “Day” filters are required in every report request.